# Reset a cumulative sum (w/o aprior knowledge of reset points) in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I am looking to deduplicate records by dropping records that occurred too closely to their previous instance (where closeness is determined as a function of timestamps).

E.g.
Actor 1 commits action 1 at times 1, 7, and 15. (with time differentials 6 and 8). If my threshold for inclusion is > 10s since last instance, you might suggest a solution like [Reset a cumulative sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349192/reset-a-cumulative-sum) where time_differential > 10 takes the place of OOS in the link.

However, I would prefer a solution that only drops the second instance since the third instance occurs 14s after the first instance. This requires 
a cumulative sum of the differentials with resets at a priori unknown times.

I have setup a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11760/2/0 w/schema

```
CREATE TABLE timed_action (
    pk INT,
    actor_id INT,
    action_id INT,
    time INT,
    show INT,
    time_since_show INT
);
```

pk is used for identification only. actor_id, action_id, and time are used as I explained above. show and time_since_show are manually calculated answer to the problem and shouldn't be used. pk 1-3 demonstrate the example from above. The only other set of instances that couldn't be solved by simply using the `time - LAG(time, 1) ...` in the DQL box, are pk 14-17 where pk 15 and 16 are dropped and pk 17 is shown despite occurring only 3s after pk 16.

I'm half-convinced this can't be accomplished in SQL w/o the use of some language augmentation like PL/pgSQL or the use of recursion, neither of which are an option for me--I am using an analytical company database (like Amazon EMR) to which I can't add language features. This question is my hail Mary before simply grouping by (timestamp / 10). Thank you.

Comment: Did you look into using `array_agg` (group by `actor_id, action_id`) + `reduce` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce)? `reduce` gives you a lot of PL/pgSQL-like power.

Comment: @artdv . . . In traditional SQL, this problem requires a recursive CTE, which Presto does not support.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I did look at that. I used ARRAY_AGG w/window function so that each record has an array of preceding + current differentials, then CROSS JOIN UNNEST (only so that I can then use this aggregate function and still be at the desired grain)... then the database erred (using the example in the docs https://pastebin.com/JjfMt1sh; not sure why; (GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR) com.facebook.presto.spi.block.IntArrayBlock ). Even if it hadn't, in order for this to work, reduce would have to run sequentially (w/o looking at src, it's not clear that it does). Gordon Linoff, thanks.

Comment: @artdv what was the error? the paste doesn't include it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Piotr Findeisen, here's an example snippet that should do the trick.

The idea is to convert the row of timestamps into an array where a `reduce` can be used. In the example below, I first create a `db0` cte where all the timestamps are in an array (sorted), `db1` where I create the array `filtered_ts` that keeps only those timestamps that satisfy your condition. The final output restores the array into a column via a `cross join unnest`.

```
with db0 as (select actor_id, action_id, array_sort(array_agg(time)) as ts from timed_action group by 1,2),

db1 as (select actor_id, action_id, reduce(ts,array[ts[0]], (s,x)->if(x-s[-1]>10,s||x,s),s->s) as filtered_ts)

select actor_id, action_id, t0 from db1 cross join unnest(filtered_ts) t(t0)
```